# Is there a hadith implying ablution is invalidated if one talks while doing it?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

In almost all regions in West Java (Indonesia), people are prohibited to talk when performing ablution. It is said to violate the process of ablution. and you have to start over again.

Is that right? Is there a hadith which explains this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing reported from the Sunnah that prohibits to talk while ablution.
- Reported in Fiqh As-Sunnah.

But, it is not recommended to talk without necessary during wudu.

Most of the scholars of Islam stated that it is recommended (mustahabb), or a proper manner (adab) of ritual ablutions to avoid worldly talk without a need that cannot be fulfilled after it.

There are [a lot of Dua's(supplications)](http://www.duas.org/wadhu.htm) taught by our Prophet(PBUH) to us while making wudu. So, it's better to make Dua' than speak. It will help to improve the quality of the Salat too.

Not only for West Java(Indonesia), Sunnah is common to the whole world, brother.

Answer (score -3):

Remember my Brothers and sisters in Islam that ever in history of prophet Muhammad (saw) talking to anyone during ablutions. Even, if they salama to him. It is then after conclusion of ablutions he would answer the greeting of salam.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the above.